# Trouble installing and opening “MAMI” package in R

Tags: r

I’ve downloaded the “MAMI” package in R but even though it’s downloaded, when I go to open it from my library, it tells me “Error in library(MAMI): there is no package called ‘MAMI.’” I had trouble downloading it as well - when I tried to download it with just “install.packages(“MAMI”)” R kept telling me “package ‘MAMI’ is not available for this version of R” so I went to the developer’s website (https://mami.r-forge.r-project.org/) and just downloaded it using the installation code there. Can someone tell me how to either redownload it in a way that will work or how to open it from my library?

Comment: Can you show your `R version`

Comment: I have Version 1.4.1106

Comment: that R version is pretty old (probably released in 2002)

Comment: That's probably the RStudio version, not the R one. Get the latter by typing `R.version` in the console, or looking for it at startup, or with `R --version` from the command line.

Comment: And when you say you downloaded it, did you then install it with `install.packages()` or `devtools` or `remotes`? You can copy the call at the bottom of the linked page and use that.